# How to make typescript synchronous executed?

Tags: typescript, async-await, synchronization

I was trying to implement an uploading image function and I have a class as followed.

```
class myClass {
  oriData: any;
  name: string;

  constructor(props) {
    this.name = props.name;
    this.oriData = this.readFile(props);
  }

  async readFile(props) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(props);
      reader.onload = () => {
        let result = reader.result;
        resolve(result);
      };
      reader.onerror = reject;
    });
  }
}

private async process(file): Promise<myClass> {
  try {
    let image = await new myClass(file);
    console.log(image.oriData);
    console.log(image.name);
    return Promise.resolve(image);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

However, when I try to get the image.oriData and image.name, image.oriData displays as Undefined but the other one is correct. I check the step and find that the process(file) will still instance myClass without waiting reader.onload finished. I believe this should be a synchronization problem. Could anyone help me improve this code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can return literally anything from a JavaScript constructor, so this is a *possible* pattern:

```
class DontDoThis {
  constructor(props) {
    this.name = props.name;
    const results = this.readFile(props);
    // As a side-effect of the promise completing, set a field
    results.then(data => this.oriData = data);

    // Force this constructor to be treated as async
    // even though we cannot say `async constructor`
    return results.then(() => this, () => this);
  }
}

async function process(...) {
  const complexData = await new DontDoThis(...);
}
```

That said, it's far, **far** better to just have a function that constructs the final value:

```
interface ImageData { name: string, oriData: any };
// This can also be a static method, e. g. `ImageData.create(...)`
async function ComplexData(props): Promise<ImageData> {
  return readFile(props).then(data => ({name: props.name, oriData: data}));
}

async function process(props) {
  const complexData = await ComplexData(props);
}
```

`ImageData` can be a class instead of an interface - the key thing to note is simply that it cannot be constructed partially - either `ComplexData` succeeds and produces an `ImageData` object or it fails and you don't get one at all.  You never have an unsafe-to-use-because-it-is-half-initialized `ImageData` object lying around.